# Find out the Phrase using three clues. combination of three words

Tags: riddle, word, cipher, wordplay, word-property

*I am 13 letter Phrase.*

My first 5 letters is a hobby with playing cards other than playing,
Next 4 letters are completed,
Last 4 letters are the natural property of a river.

*What am i?*

Comment: Suggestion: Make it 'phrase' not 'word' because it isn't a 13 letter word - it's two words

Comment: changed.. @BeastlyGerbil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word is:

> STACK OVERFLOW. Playing cards=Stack, Completed=Over. Property of river=Flow